# Characterization for unprovable formulas for first-order logic

Tags: first-order-logic, incompleteness, provability

Is there any existing work on characterizations of the unprovable formulas in (general) first-order logic? i.e. Gödel's incompletness result constructs an explicit formula that is valid but unprovable: are there other not-so-scary examples of unprovable formulas? are there some attempts/theories to characterize the explicit self-referential trait which prevents these formulas to be proven in any particular calculus?

Comment: There's a massive amount of work on this. For a good introduction, see Kunen's *Set Theory: an Introduction to Independence Proofs*. The book is dedicated to exploring propositions that can be neither proved nor disproved within the normal rules of set theory. But there is also no algorithm that can determine whether a statement is provable from a given set of axioms.

Comment: @MarkSaving Thank you for this comment. In particular that there is no (general) algorithm to determine whether a statement is provable. I was heavily verbally attacked by a user (I do not mention the name) for the statement that it is not known whether the Collatz conjecture is provable (unless of course we add it as an axiom).

Comment: "Gödel's incompletness result constructs an explicit formula that is valid but unprovable" This isn't correct: the Godel sentence is *not* valid (= true in every structure), or even true in every model of the "base theory" we're looking at (usually first-order Peano arithmetic or similar). It is merely true in *one particular* model (namely the actual natural numbers). Indeed, [Godel's *completeness* theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) (not a typo!) shows that validity and provability coincide.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for your comment. Sorry for the confusion, I'm a beginner to this topic, so I might not formulate things properly (any feedback is appreciated!). I'm aware of the completeness theorem (both forms); and indeed I was more interested in the natural number model per se, but perhaps assumed that some results would generalize over to other models. The book mentioned by Mark Saving above is, I believe, mostly devoted to forcing (correct me if I'm wrong). So I guess my question could be rephrased as _"how to recognize the trait that makes a Gödel sentence unprovable"_?

Comment: However, he also points that _"But there is also no algorithm that can determine whether a statement is provable from a given set of axioms."_. @MarkSaving could you give me some pointers on the derivation of this result? Thanks!

Comment: That we cannot in general predict whether a statement (assuming it is true) is provable within some strong enough theory is closely related to the halting problem. We can search for a proof and will find it eventually, if it exists, but if not, we can never be sure that there is none.

Comment: @Peter I understand this is the case because first-order formulas are recursively enumerable. But how does this imply that the complement set of those formulas is not recognizable by, say, some other suitable calculi?

Comment: @ale64bit Consider some basic axiomatisation of the natural numbers which is strong enough to make the statement "Program P terminates in x steps". Let's also suppose all of the axioms here are actually true statements about the natural numbers. Then we can prove "there exists x such that P terminates in x steps" if and only if it is actually true that program P eventually halts. So we would be able to solve the halting problem with an algorithm if we could determine whether "there exists x such that P terminates in x steps" is provable.